# Как получить из даты текущий день недели?

Tags: c#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    int dayofweek = (int)date.DayOfWeek;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

}

Пытаюсь получить текущий день недели, но выдает такую ошибку:
 "Инициализатор поля не может обращаться к нестатическому полю, методу или свойству"

Comment: Это рабочий участок кода. Покажите целиком весь код.

Comment: `int dayofweek = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime date;
int dayofweek;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    date = DateTime.Now;
    dayofweek = (int)date.DayOfWeek;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, вы пытаетесь инициализировать поле класса `dayofweek`, опираясь на значение другого, нестатического поля `date`. Так как порядок инициализации полей не регламентирован, то компилятор имеет полное право инициализировать поле `dayofweek` перед инициализацией поля `date`, что приведет к указанной вами ошибке. Поэтому синтаксический анализатор заблаговременно предупреждает о возможной ошибке и не дает завершить компиляцию.

Если какому-либо полю нужна сложная инициализация или начальное значение поля зависит от начального значения другого поля, то инициализацию данного поля нужно производить в конструкторе класса, который именно для этого и предназначен см. решение предложенное [@Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705280/198316).

Альтернативное решение - вместо связанных полей, использовать вычисляемое свойство, например так:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

    int dayofweek => (int)date.DayOfWeek;//в виде лямбды
    int dayofweek //в более привычном виде
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return (int)date.DayOfWeek; 
        } 
    }
    .....
}
```

В случае тесно связанных значений, как в вашем случае, такое решение позволит не заботиться о синхронизации, при изменении значения основного поля, т.к. `dayofweek` вычисляется при обращении к нему, а благодаря тому, что `DateTime` - структура, а структуры в C# являются типом-значением (value-type), можно опустить проверку на null поля `date` перед вычислением.